# Using string variable to decide, which multi-dimensional array to use

Tags: vb.net, variables, multidimensional-array

I have about 17 2-d arrays which need to be accessed based on user selection. I'd like to use a variable to represent these, but I get this error:

> Too many arguments to 'Public ReadOnly Default Property Chars(index As Integer) As Char'

Here is a sample of my code:

```
ElseIf EcoType = "MB" Then

        If MatrixVeg.Substring(0, 2) = "CO" Then

            x = Array.IndexOf(CO, MatrixVeg)
            EcoGroup = "MBCO"

        ElseIf MatrixVeg.Substring(0, 2) = "HL" Then

            x = Array.IndexOf(HL, MatrixVeg)
            EcoGroup = "MBHL"

        ElseIf MatrixVeg.Substring(0, 2) = "OF" Then

            x = Array.IndexOf(OFF, MatrixVeg)
            EcoGroup = "MBOF"

        ElseIf MatrixVeg.Substring(0, 2) = "OW" Then

            x = Array.IndexOf(OW, MatrixVeg)
            EcoGroup = "MBOW"

        ElseIf MatrixVeg.Substring(0, 2) = "SP" Then

            x = Array.IndexOf(SP, MatrixVeg)
            EcoGroup = "MBSP"

        ElseIf MatrixVeg.Substring(0, 2) = "WC" Then

            x = Array.IndexOf(WC, MatrixVeg)
            EcoGroup = "MBWC"

        ElseIf MatrixVeg.Substring(0, 2) = "WD" Then

            x = Array.IndexOf(WD, MatrixVeg)
            EcoGroup = "MBWD"

        End If

    End If

    y = Array.IndexOf(ST, MatrixSoil)

    Ecosite = EcoGroup(y, x)

    Return Ecosite
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try replacing Ecosite = EcoGroup(y, x) with Ecosite = EcoGroup.Substring(y, x) ? EcoGroup(y,x) calls the Chars() functions wich returns the character at the index provided, and it only accpets one parameter.

Comment: Can you tell I'm not a programmer! NullReferenceException for that one.

Comment: That probably means x or y has no values (Nothing), you should probably debug your code and check if those variables recieve any values, since in the code you posted everything is behind IFs, the value of  MatrixVeg.Substring(0, 2) probably doesnt match any of your conditions, thus resulting in x having a null value.

Comment: When I hard-code in one of the arrays such as: Ecosite = ACIH(y,x) it works, but if I use Ecosite = EcoGroup.Substring(y,x) i get an out of range exception even thought the x,y values are the same in both.

Comment: Stepping through the code, what is the value of `EcoGroup`, `x`, and `y`? When you do `EcoGroup.Substring(y, x)` it is taking a substring of the string "MBWD" (for example), starting at `y` of length `x`.

Comment: Perhaps you could use a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to hold the arrays - if you had a a `Dictionary(Of String, Integer(,))` (assuming your arrays are of integers) then you could access each array with a string.

Answer (score 1):

From your code and comments, it appears that `MCO`, `MBHL`,`MBOF`, etc. are *variables*, but in your `If` statements, you assign Ecogroup *string values* instead of the variables themselves.

All you should have to do to fix this is remove the quotation marks when you assign the values (e.g. `EcoGroup = MBCO`).

On a stylistic note, I'd recommend using a `Select Case` statement for this situation. Take a look at this revised code:

```
ElseIf EcoType = "MB" Then
    Select Case MatrixVeg.Substring(0, 2)
        Case "CO"
            x = Array.IndexOf(CO, MatrixVeg)
            EcoGroup = MBCO
        Case "HL"
            x = Array.IndexOf(HL, MatrixVeg)
            EcoGroup = MBHL
        Case "OF"
            x = Array.IndexOf(OFF, MatrixVeg)
            EcoGroup = MBOF
        Case "OW"
            x = Array.IndexOf(OW, MatrixVeg)
            EcoGroup = MBOW
        Case "SP"
            x = Array.IndexOf(SP, MatrixVeg)
            EcoGroup = MBSP
        Case "WC"
            x = Array.IndexOf(WC, MatrixVeg)
            EcoGroup = MBWC
        Case "WD"
            x = Array.IndexOf(WD, MatrixVeg)
            EcoGroup = MBWD
        End Select
End If

y = Array.IndexOf(ST, MatrixSoil)
Ecosite = EcoGroup(y, x)
Return Ecosite
```